# Cannot have RabbitMQ Clojure client working

Tags: node.js, clojure, rabbitmq

I have 2 clients of my RabbitMQ instance but I do not manage to have the Clojure version working. I'm probably missing some RabbitMQ config but cannot figure out what.
My exchange is data and the queue is ALERT.

Any idea what is missing in the Clojure version ?

Working Node.js RabbitMQ client

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://192.168.99.100', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
  var ex = 'data';
  ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {durable: true});
  ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true}, function(err, q) {
    console.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C');
    ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, 'ALERT');
    ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] %s: '%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: true});
  });
});
```

Non working Clojure RabbitMQ client

```
(ns notifications.core
  (:gen-class))
;; Import methods from langohr
(require '[langohr.core      :as rmq]
         '[langohr.channel   :as lch]
         '[langohr.queue     :as lq]
         '[langohr.exchange  :as le]
         '[langohr.consumers :as lc]
         '[langohr.basic     :as lb])

(defn start-consumer
  "Starts a consumer bound to the given topic exchange in a separate thread"
  [ch topic-name]
  (let [queue-name "ALERT"
        handler    (fn [ch {:keys [content-type delivery-tag type] :as meta} ^bytes payload]
                     (println (format "received %s" (String. payload "UTF-8"))))]
    (lq/declare ch queue-name {:exclusive true})
    (lq/bind    ch queue-name topic-name)
    (lc/subscribe ch queue-name handler)))

(defn -main
  "Start RabbitMQ consumer"
  [& args]
  (let [conn  (rmq/connect {:host "192.168.99.100"})
        ch    (lch/open conn)
        ex    "data"]
    (le/declare ch ex "direct" {:durable true})
    (start-consumer ch ex)))
```

**Update**

On RabbitMQ side, I can see that the Clojure client connects successfully but it does not received the messages sent to exchange data / queue "ALERT". I do not have any error message.

Comment: Do you get any specific error/exception? or does it claim to be connected and not actually send any messages?

Comment: I see the connection occuring in RabbitMQ logs but when I send a message to MQ, it's not received by the Clojure client (while it's received by the Node.js)

Comment: Can you be sure that it's not working by running it from the terminal using "lein repl"and make sure that the output is not going to the *nrepl-server your-project-name* buffer if you are using emacs.

Comment: If I understand your clients code correctly, they are not doing the same thing: your Clojure client creates a queue named `ALERT`, however, your Node.js client creates a queue named automatically by the server, bound to the exchange with the `ALERT` routing key. So what exactly is your publisher doing?

Comment: @Jean-SébastienPédron I think I mismatch the fanout vs direct (+ routing key) behavior. My nodejs publisher is using ch.publish('data', 'ALERT', new Buffer(message)); so using the "ALERT" routing key. The node client is correctly bind with the routing key whereas the Clojure client uses an invalid queue name. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Both clients are declaring valid queues. In the case of your Node.js client, the created queue is bound with the `ALERT` routing key, but in your Clojure client, the created queue is bound with an empty routing key. If your publisher sends a message to the `data` exchange with the `ALERT` routing key, the message will be queued on the queue created by your Node.js client because the routing key matches. However, it will be dropped in the case of your Clojure client because the routing key doesn't match. With the informations you provided, I can write a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more discussion in the question's comments, here is what your clients do:

1. Your Node.js client creates the `data` direct exchange and a queue automatically named by the server, then it binds the created queue to the `data` exchange with the `ALERT` routing key. Here is a schema:

   ```
   exchange:"data" --["ALERT"]--> queue:$generated_name
   ```
2. Your Clojure client creates the `data` direct exchange and the `ALERT` queue, then it binds the created queue to the `data` exchange with an empty routing key.

   ```
   exchange:"data" --[""]--> queue:"ALERT"
   ```

Your publisher sends a message to the `data` exchange, with `ALERT` as the routing key. So in situation #1, the message is correctly routed to the queue, no matter its generated name, because the routing key matches the one set on the binding. However, in situation #2, the message is dropped because there is no queue bound to the `data` exchange with a matching routing key.

If you want the queue to be named `ALERT` and you want messages with the `ALERT` routing key to be delivered to this, you must either use the `""` exchange (its name is an empty string, the routing key indicates the name of the queue to use) or bind the `ALERT` queue with the `ALERT` routing key.